# How to make pie chart in crystal reports from one record?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, pie-chart

I am using crystal reports with vb.net. I have a datatable with columns (total,rejected,accepted).The data changes according to a query. by the way the table always has one record only.

total     rejected    accepted
60220.196   38107.94    22112.256

I want to put a pie chart in the report. the size of the chart is the total. the slices are (rejected, accepted).

in chart expert, I didn't know how to set the data to show the desired chart.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctG6B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `On change of` to `For all records`, then choos your value fields:

[image]

Comment: How to change the  labels of the viewed data) so I can show it as accepted and rejected rather than sum of table.rejected and sum of table.rejected

Comment: In preview mode, select the label you want to change in the legend. Then right-click it, select `Edit Axis Label` and rename it.